# Batch File: How to copy a number of files from subfolders and organize them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried with `/S` to copy the files from subdirectory but don't work.
it copies only from the main directory `Source` ,

Any ideas?

then if I have 10 files to copy and 5 subdirectories,
2 files from each subdirectory will be copied and if one subdirectory get empty the batch file will copy the rest of them that have files in it and make the math.

all files already copied will be added in a .txt file, like a database and will be skipped next run of the batch.

when the files remained to copy are less than `MaxLimit`  than the .txt file database will be deleted and the batch file will start again.

the .txt will be created again with first files copied ..  and so on.. an infinite number of times

```
@echo off

set Source=E:\teste-batch-file\original\
set Target=E:\teste-batch-file\final

set MaxLimit=10

for /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%G in ('dir  /A-D  /B  "%Source%\*.mp4" ^| find  /v /n ""') do (
copy /y "%Source%\%%~nxH" "%Target%"
if %%G==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
 )
```

thank you for helping me out

Comment: Your question seems to be lookong for more than a solution for a single specific and reproducible programming code issue. Please rewrite your question to limit it accordingly. We are not here to offer code for an entire task, our job is to help you to fix the code you have written for that task, if it fails to do what it was written to do. The code you have submitted, does not attempt the task you have laid out.

Comment: You need `xcopy` to recurse. The remainder of the question seems unrelated to that problem.